# Proof of sum of a series $a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $n\in N={{1,2,3...}}$
I have a function $$f_n(x)=x^3 +nx - 1$$ with solution $a_n$ with $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=0$$ and sum of the series is $f(x)$.

I also know that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$$

I found the interval of convergence to be $|x|<1=(-1,1) $ by the ratio test, from the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$ Using the fact that I was given the limit of  $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ to be $1$.

Using this information, I want to prove that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} \int_0^xf(t) dt=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n+1}$$

Comment: Please check the line with the limit, the integral and the sum! As written, it does not make sense.

Comment: It is straight from the problem set. I added some other information, it might clear things up.

Comment: Could $n $ goes to (1^-).

Comment: The first sentence makes no sense. What's the solution of a function? Sum of what series? And then you have not answered @Peter 's question.

Comment: The entire question is incoherent as it stands. What is $a_n$? It apparently is the solution of something to do with $f_n$. One interpretation is that $f_n(a_n)=0$. That looks possible, with $a_n\sim1/n$. But then the sum of “the series” is $f(x)$. But *what* series? Perhaps the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$? That is mentioned, but why at the end? The objection from @Peter does not seem to have been taken care of, either. I am beginning to think I understand the question, but there is too much guesswork. I'm voting to close.

Comment: All I can say is that I agree. But this is all the information given. My first guess was that $f_n(x)$ is the series. I agree the placement of $\sum a_n x^n$ is poor. I will change that.

Comment: Fixed @YvesDaoust

Comment: @themli what about the equal sign ? Grrrr

Answer (score 1):

We compute easily the derivative of $f_n$, and find that $f_n$ is strictly increasing. So there exists a unique solution $a_n$ for the equation $f_n(x)=0$. As $f_n(0)=-1$ and $f_n(1)=n$, we get that $0<a_n <1$. We have $na_n=1-a_n^3$, hence $0\leq n a_n \leq 1$, and $na_n\to 1$. Put $a_n=\frac{1}{n}-b_n$. By the above, $\displaystyle 0\leq b_n\leq \frac{1}{n^4}$. If we put $\displaystyle g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}b_n x^n$, we have that the series $g$ is normally convergent on $[0,1]$, hence the limit of $\int_0^xg(t)dt$ as $x\to 1$, $x<1$ is $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{b_n}{n+1}$. Now
$$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n x^n=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n}-g(x)=-\log(1-x)-g(x)$$
and hence 
$$\int_0^x f(t)dt=-\int_0^x\log(1-t)dt-\int_0^xg(t)dt$$

and to finish you have only to prove that the limit of $-\int_0^x\log(1-t)$ as $x\to 1$, $x<1$, is $1=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

Comment: Since this is about the convergence and limit of a power series at the boundary of the interval of convergence, [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem) might come in handy. But by all means, a hands-on approach is just fine in this case.